# Importing multiple projects and single projects into Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I need to be able to import all of our projects in android studio and i need to be able to import just a single project, and its dependencies, into android studio.

---

Current project structure:

- branch/

  - Apps/

    - Project1/

      - build.gradle
    - Project2/

      - build.gradle
    - Project3/

      - build.gradle
    - build.gradle
    - settings.gradle
    - gradlew
    - gradlew.bat
    - gradle/
  - OtherStuff/

---

I can import the `branch/Apps/build.gradle` fine and it imports all the projects under `Apps` and compiles all the projects in `settings.gradle` and works fine. However, i also need to be able to import just one project, and its dependencies, into android studio and it work fine.

Right now when i try to import the `branch/Apps/Project1/build.gradle` Android studio gives the following error:

```
You are using an old, unsupported version of Gradle. Please use version 1.8 or greater.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)
```

How can i import a single project and have it use the gradle wrapper that the MASS import of all the projects is using? Or is there a better way to handle this situation? Maybe i am just doing it completely wrong.

This effects Android Studio Version is 0.3.7 and 0.4.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio expects to see a `settings.gradle` file at the root directory of its project, and likes to have the Gradle wrapper files at the root as well. If you're trying to open, say, **Project1** as an independent project, that's the problem you're running into -- neither of those things is in **Project1**'s directory. If **Project1** is just a module in the larger **Apps** project, those things aren't necessary.

What are you trying to do? Maybe there's a better approach rather than opening a subproject independently.

EDIT:

It works for me if I copy the Gradle wrapper files (`gradlew`, `gradlew.bat`, and the `gradle` directory) into the subproject's directory, and also add a `settings.gradle` file that looks like this:

```
include ':'
```

Here's a screenshot of my project's layout, where I've edited LibA to be able to be opened independently:

[image: Screenshot of Project view showing files in app and LibA directories]

Note that if your subprojects have dependencies on each other (e.g. Project1 depends on Project2), then this scheme isn't going to work. Right now Android Studio would only understand that in the context of a larger project with a root directory that can encompass all dependencies.

Comment: My objective is to have the capability to open all the projects by importing the `branch/Apps/build.gradle` and import individual projects by importing an individual projects `build.gradle`. For our project to move to gradle, this is needed.

Comment: You can do this with maven importing into Android studio and you can do this with Eclipse.

Comment: That much is evident, but doesn't really answer the question of why it isn't good enough to just open the larger Apps project if you want to work on one of the subprojects. I'm not sure of the use case where you want to sometimes work on them in the context of a larger multimodule project and sometimes not. If you really need to work on subprojects independently, the best answer may be to make them standalone Android library projects that output AARs to a local or central Maven repository.

Comment: I agree that it seems silly. But it is a requirement for our project to switch to using gradle.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the structure of a working solution, and to also show how to set up the settings.gradle file.

Comment: I knew that your solution above would work. I was hoping for a way that i do not have to have the wrapper in each individual project. That is a lot of clutter that should not be needed.

Comment: You could maybe try symlinking the wrapper in each subdirectory, or you could actually install Gradle somewhere and have it use that installation instead of the wrapper. If you go down the latter path, you'll have to deal with occasional version problems every time we release a new Android Gradle plugin that needs a new version of Gradle, but it should work. Another disadvantage of this approach is it makes your project less portable -- another developer who wants to set it up on his machine will need to install the right version of Gradle.

Comment: Could i just commit the gradle version into our repo and have it reference that version of gradle? I have tried using the gradle version that is in the plugins directory of android studio and it continues to give me the same error.

Comment: The installation of Gradle that ships with Android Studio isn't the one that's used for its Gradle builds; that's part of the general IntelliJ support for Gradle-based projects as part of Community/ Ultimate Edition. Sorry, I know it's confusing. 0.3.7 ships with Gradle 1.9, which is actually too new for Android Gradle projects (since we use internal APIs at the moment, we're tied to specific releases and aren't forward-compatible). If you install Gradle 1.8 somewhere and reference it, it should work. Whether you check into source control is up to you but in general it's probably a bad idea.

Comment: Interesting. That actually cleared up several questions we have been having. The version stuff has been very confusing. I will try the download and see how it works out.

Comment: That worked, kinda. I was able to import the project into Android Studio. However, it is still showing all my other projects in my `Apps` directory in Android Studio, even though i only imported `project1`. Why does Android Studio continue to show all of the projects under `Apps`?

Comment: Yeah, i am actually still seeing other projects when i try to just import `project1`. Even if i change the filter for the project view. I will have `project1` and `project2` still show up. What we want is to be able to import `project1` and it only imports `project1` and its dependencies, not all the other projects that are in the `App` directory or associated with the `settings.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to edit the gradle wrapper settings in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and change gradle version to 1.8.

Comment: In my `gradle-wrapper.properties` it is set to `http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip`. Is this what you are referring too?

Comment: Yes it is. Check the currently used wrapper maybe. Preferences>Gradle>"Use default gradle wrapper" is checked ?

Comment: When i try to import `Project1` it will only allow me to select `Use customizable gradle wrapper` or `Use local gradle distribution`.